# HTTP_REFERER works fine in browser but breaks in download manager

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-referer

I've used the following code to limit access to my files:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain[NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?domain.*$ [NC] 
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|php|rar)$ - [F]
```

Browser can't start downloading of `rar` files which means rewrite code works fine at this level but I can download them using IDM (Internet Download Manager). any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: You should check this with your IDM -- see what headers it sends. Quite likely it's intelligent enough and remembers the initial referral page (or uses domain name as a referral automatically). In such case you are unlikely to do anything here (referral header can **easily** be spoofed).

Comment: Thanks, yes you're right. It uses domain as referer. I'm not sure what I can do.

Comment: Well .. you can base your checks on cookies instead of referral -- it's more stable/accurate approach compared to referral one. When user visits the page special cookie will be sent (not necessarily permanent one; e.g. for a session duration only). If download manager will be used, it may ignore/forget about cookie (especially if you add time-based cookie, that would require re-validation (new one must be set) after few hours).